# Multiindex Dataframe, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to manipulate a data from excel file, however it has merged heading for columns, I managed to transform them in pandas. Please see example of original data below.
[image: Original data]

So I transformed to this format.
[image: Transformed data]

and my final goal is to get the format below and plot brand items and their sales quantity and prices over the period, however I don't know how to access info in multiindex dataframe.  Could you please suggest something. Thanks.
[image: Final data]

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('path.xls', sheet_name = 'data', header = [0,1])

a = df.columns.get_level_values(0).to_series()
b = a.mask(a.str.startswith('Unnamed')).fillna('')
df.columns = [b, df.columns.get_level_values(1)]
df.drop(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: how working `df = pd.read_excel('path.xls', sheet_name = 'data', header = [0,1], index_col=[0,1,2,3,4,5])` ?

Answer (score 0):

try pandas groupby or pivot_table.  The pivot table include index, columns, values and aggfunc.  It really nice for summarizing data.